# Is my outcome wrong? (Evaluating a logarithm)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$log\sqrt [ 4 ]{ x^2+y^2 } $$

$$log\sqrt { x+y } $$

$$logx^{ 1/2 }+log^{ 1/2 }$$

$$\frac { 1 }{ 2 }log (x+y)$$

The answer key saids:

$$\frac { 1 }{ 4 } log(x^2+y^2)$$

Comment: Yes it is wrong

Comment: but doesn't the 4th root cancel out the squares within the radical?

Comment: In one term only, in this case you have more than one term added

Comment: $\log \sqrt[4]{1^2+1^2} \neq \log \sqrt{1+1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use only the following
$$\log a^n=n\log a \\ \log a*b=\log a+\log b \\ \log(a/b)=\log a-\log b$$

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid your answer is incorrect.

You should get this:

\begin{align*}
&\log \sqrt[4]{x^2+y^2}\\
&=\log(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{4}\log(x^2+y^2)
\end{align*}

You should note that $(a+b)^n\neq a^n+b^n$ in general, so $(a^2+b^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}\neq a^{\frac{1}{2}}+b^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: This is definitely right. Gotta watch your logarithm rules...